# Why can't I get this with Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Can someone assist me with a very simple problem. I cannot get these two vectors to be orthogonal using Gram-Schmidt:

> $\{(1,-1,1),(2,1,1)\}$

What am I doing wrong?

> Let $v_1=(1,-1,1)$.
>
> $v_2 =
> > (2,1,1)-\frac{\langle(2,1,1),(1,-1,1)\rangle}{\lvert (1,-1,1) \rvert^2}(1,-1,1)$  =$(2,1,1)-\frac{1}{3}(1,-1,1)$ This gives me
>   $(\frac{5}{3},\frac{4}{3},-\frac{2}{3})$ Which is not orthogonal to
>   $(1,-1,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

The numerator of the fraction should be 
$$
\langle(2,1,1),(1,-1,1)\rangle
$$

**Edit**

After your correction, I can see that there is still an error, given that

$$
\frac{\langle(2,1,1),(1,-1,1)\rangle}{|(1,-1,1)|^2}=\frac{2}{3}
$$

Comment: Yes that was my typing error and it that numerator which is giving me one third as dot product

Comment: @ZiloreMumba: see the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks @enzotib I was doing $<(2,1,1),(1,-1,1)> =(2)*(1)+(1)*(-1)+(1)*(1)$ for the numerator, which gives me $\frac{1}{3}$ overall. Your answer is correct, but how does the dot product become 2 not 1?.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba, I cannot believe you setup the correct operation and get the wrong result: $(2)*(1)+(1)*(-1)+(1)*(1)=2-1+1=2$.

Comment: Thanks very, I also cannot believe why I was not getting it until now. Thank you very much, strange things happen sometimes.